# How can I get reports of all memory usages and cpu usages by App Service on a single plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Is there a way of showing memory/cpu consumption by App Service for all app services on an Azure App Service Plan?

Alternatively, is there any way of generating a report of resource consumption for multiple selected App Services?

UPDATE: The Metrics per Instance (App Service) report does not show each app on the plan. Only the apps in the resource group for the app you are viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the metrics per instance - app service plan section under the web app in Azure portal

Comment: See good post by Hanselman on that topic: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudRunningAndManagingLOTSOfWebAppsOnASingleAzureAppService.aspx

Comment: I will check again to confirm later but if I recall then this does not work for me. I think it only works if the apps are in the same resource group or something

Comment: Downvoting. I can confirm this does NOT work. Portal only shows the app services in a resource group. We have 20 to 30 apps in different resource groups (security) on the one plan. Updating question.